# Trouble understanding the differences between 2 sets of code that get the same results

Tags: c, function, loops

I am taking a course in C and just started working with functions. I completed my code for this chapter's lab and it runs properly. I then went and looked at the lab's included correct answer code and it is different from mine.

Mine has the "printf" in the function's call in the main area, but the lab's correct answer code has the printf outside of the main area, yet they both get the exact same result when you run the programs.

This makes it very confusing for me. It seems like there are always 2 different ways to do the exact same thing in C.

Can someone please explain this to me?

My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void closing(void);
int addSix(int x);

int main()
{

    closing();
    closing();

    for(int index=0; index<10; index++) {

        printf("Result: %d\n", addSix(index));
    }





    return 0;
}

void closing(void)
{
    printf("That's all folks!\n");
}

int addSix(int x)
{
    int result = x+6;

    return result;
}
```

The lab's correct answer code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void closing(void);
void addSix(int x);


int main ()
{
    closing();
    closing();

    for(int i = 0; i<10; i++){
        addSix(i);
    }



    return 0;
}

void closing(void)
{
    printf("That's all folks.\n");
}

void addSix(int x)
{
    int result = x+6;
    printf("Result: %d\n", result);
}
```

Comment: There are dozens of different ways to do anything in C, or any other programming language for that matter.  Your code is actually functionally equivalent to the "correct" answer.

Comment: There are not only two ways, but many ways to do same thing in C.

Comment: You can't say it's correct or not by the code, if the result is the same and it's the expected, the code is correct. Yours is as good as the solution.

Comment: The function name is `addSix` not `addSixAndPrint`. Your code is more correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to conceptualize this is by walking through the code line by line. Your `printf` call calls `addSix` and prints the result. The lab's version does the printing from inside the `addSix` function. There will always be multiple ways to write code. In this case, yours is just as valid as the official version. For what it's worth, I think yours is better.

Comment: I agree that the instructor's way is less elegant.

Answer (score 1):

There are literally hundreds of different ways to do it. The way that your instructor is showing you is to create a variable and make an assignment, then pass that variable to the printf function.

It's considered (slightly) more advanced to simply pass a one-liner function as an argument to a different function, which is what you did. It's no more or less wrong; it's just different.

The reason theirs works is because they have a variable, result, which contains a value passed to the printf function.

The reason yours works is because you pass the return value of the function directly to the printf function *without using an intermediate variable*.